# Modal form not opening on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, modalviewcontroller

I have the following angular html in an attempt to open a modal form on clicking a button. The code creates the button just fine but on click it doesn't do anything.

Why is the button not opening the form?

```js
var myMod = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function() {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function() {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
          <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </script>
  <h1>GWAT Websites and Designs</h1>
  <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Submit new post</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you try defining `modalInstance` outside the scope of the `open` function?

Comment: Not sure you need the variable `modalInstance` just `$modal.open().then` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made these changes:

1. include `<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>`
2. add `ng-app="plunker"`
3. register controllers: `myMod.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ModalDemoCtrl);`
   `myMod.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ModalInstanceCtrl);`
4. Add `<p>Selected: {{selected}}</p>` to view selected item from modal
5. Change `$modal` to `$uibModal` and `$modalInstance` to `$uibModalInstance`

```js
var myMod = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function(selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function() {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) { 
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
};

myMod.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', ModalDemoCtrl);
myMod.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ModalInstanceCtrl);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>

<div ng-app='plunker' ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
          <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </script>
  <h1>GWAT Websites and Designs</h1>
  <p>Selected: {{selected}}</p>
  <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Submit new post</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help so if im understanding correctly i was mostly somewhat outdated with how modal forms now work?

Comment: Yes, only older versions of ui-bootstrap library used `$modal` and `$modalInstace`